# Combining multiple string arrays into one

Tags: java, arrays, string

Basically I have multiple string arrays and I want to combine them.

Not just extend the first array but combine `a[0]` and `b[0]` into single line.

like so:

```
String[] a = {"line1", "line2"};
String[] b = {"line3", "line4"};
String[] c; 
Combine code here
c[0] == "line1line3";
c[1] == "line2line4";
```

I'm using commons lang v3 if that's any help.

I can combine the 2 arrays with

c = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b);

But that's just makes c = "line1", "line2", "line3", "line4"

Anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the arrays have the same length, what about

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i){
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

just concatenating corresponding strings in a loop?

Comment: a & b should always be same length although unknown, so yeah that works aslong as i set the length of c. Thanks, so simple :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`StringUtils.join`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) from commons lang to "glue" the strings together:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != c.length ; i++) {
    c[i] = StrungUtils.join(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

This *might* be a bit faster in case that you need to join more than two arrays, but in case of just two arrays it will almost certainly be slower.

Comment: That's from an external library.

Comment: @Mob the OP says he's already using it: "I'm using commons lang v3 if that's any help."

Comment: That does the wrong thing, if I understand the OP correctly, that concatenates each array and puts the concatenated strings in the slots of `c`, but as I understand the OP, (s)he wants to combine corresponding entries of the different arrays.

Comment: OP wants to join a[0] and b[0] not a[0], a[1].

Comment: Thanks for this, there's actually 8 arrays so this is definitely helpfull!

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, I completely misread the direction of joining: I thought he wanted to join them "horizontally", not "vertically". I fixed the answer to match the expected direction of joining the strings, but with only two arrays to join, your answer remains a much faster alternative (so I +1'ed it). Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my answer!

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Now I can +1 this too, very useful with more than say 3 arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = new String[a.length];
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to add handling of invalid indices, but here you go:

```
String[] c = new String[len];
for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```